# In MVC 3 and IIS 7.5 server intermittent page response issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In our IIS 7.5 server(load balance server) system intermittently delays the page response of an ASP.NET MVC 3 application up to 90 seconds or so, even though same page renders in 0-1 second most of the times. This happens randomly to particular page, and for POST type requests. Not able to tack the issue through IIS or fiddler. The request is http 302 post and If I run the fiddler or in chrome the issue is not coming. I am currently using IE 8. Much appriciated for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it is due to the double post call in Ajax.